# JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING removed in php 5.5?

Tags: php, json

It seems to me that the constant `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is removed from [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP 5.5.

I use PHP "5.5.3-1ubuntu2"  (Ubuntu 13.10) and got this error since the update from PHP 5.4 (Ubuntu 13.04):

> Warning: json_decode(): option JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING not implemented in ...

Is there any evidence that this is removed?

---

EDIT:

I don't need that function so I added this constant:

```
define('USE_JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING',(!version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.5', '>=') and defined('JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING')));
```

and wherever I use  json_decode(), I use this:

```
if(USE_JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING) $j= json_decode($json ,true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING );
else $j=  json_decode($json,true );
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any information in the changelog about this so I would assume it **could** be a bug...

Comment: I'm running `PHP 5.5.1-1~dotdeb.1` which does support the constant, so if it was removed, it would have to have been in version 5.5.2 or 5.5.3.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned here already, this error seems to come from a buggy version of pecl-json-c, which Ubuntu packages as an alias for php5-json because of licensing issues.

A work around that I found, thanks to the [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) project, is to check for the `JSON_C_VERSION` constant that is set by pecl-json-c, instead of `USE_JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`. (Since `USE_JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is defined, but not implemented).

Here is the code from the [JWT project](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/Authentication/JWT.php#L210):

```
<?php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') && !(defined('JSON_C_VERSION') && PHP_INT_SIZE > 4)) {
    /** In PHP >=5.4.0, json_decode() accepts an options parameter, that allows you
     * to specify that large ints (like Steam Transaction IDs) should be treated as
     * strings, rather than the PHP default behaviour of converting them to floats.
     */
    $obj = json_decode($input, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
} else {
    /** Not all servers will support that, however, so for older versions we must
     * manually detect large ints in the JSON string and quote them (thus converting
     *them to strings) before decoding, hence the preg_replace() call.
     */
    $max_int_length = strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) - 1;
    $json_without_bigints = preg_replace('/:\s*(-?\d{'.$max_int_length.',})/', ': "$1"', $input);
    $obj = json_decode($json_without_bigints);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give errors in case inside a large string, there is a large number inside the text?. the regex should only numbers that are still "outside" of qoutes

Comment: I can't take credit for writing this regex - but taking a 2nd look at it there *is* a bug: if a long integer is inside a string **and** follows a ":", it will be quoted (even though it is already inside a quoted string). It does not quote long integers inside string otherwise though. Perhaps when I have time I'll work on a fancy RegEx that truly only matches unquoted long integers.

Comment: This Regex is breaking some Twitter responses. Care to offer up an improved version?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was [introduced](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520) to some Linux distributions due to LICENSE concerns and you are using an affected [json-c PECL module](http://pecl.php.net/package/jsonc).

My suggestion would be to use an newer version of the module.

Comment: Yes, there is a new and FREE JSON extension. I do not recommend using the old one. Check with the developers on this.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the relevant module?