# decode return json from firebase

Tags: php, json, firebase, push-notification, decode

I want to decode this json from url-> "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" but unfortunately I did not succeed, I really do not know what to do Please help me, in below you see my code :

```
    function decodeJSON($ids)
{
    $MyString = sendFCMToMultiple($ids);
    echo "return:" . $MyString . PHP_EOL;
    //$MyDecode = json_decode($MyString, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    //$MyDecode = json_decode($MyString, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    $MyDecode = json_decode($MyString);
    $MultiCastID = $MyDecode->multicast_id;
    $Success = $MyDecode->success;
    $Failure = $MyDecode->failure;
    $CanonicalIDS = $MyDecode->canonical_ids;
    $Results = $MyDecode->results;
    //echo 'Var MultiCastID=' . var_dump($MultiCastID) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'MultiCastID to Str=' . number_format($MultiCastID, 0, '.', '') . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'MultiCastID=' . $MultiCastID . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Success=' . $Success . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Failure=' . $Failure . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'CanonicalIDS=' . $CanonicalIDS . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Results=' . $Results . PHP_EOL;

    echo '=================================================================' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**this is orginal and primary json from fcm url:**

```
{
  "multicast_id": 7640049088650537742,
  "success": 2,
  "failure": 2,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    },
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1513401047065944%93a06d80f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1513401047066546%93a06d80f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

**this is return and showed from my code :**

```
{"multicast_id":7640049088650537742,"success":2,"failure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1513401047065944%93a06d80f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1513401047066546%93a06d80f9fd7ecd"}]}
MultiCastID to Str=7640049088650537984
MultiCastID=7.6400490886505E+18
Success=2
Failure=2
CanonicalIDS=0
Results=
=================================================================
```

**And but My problems:**

first : I can't use json string to json_decode($MyString, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING) and returned null values for all keys; That's why I say that I want string value or integer type for multicast_id key but json_decode itself automatic big integer to float number and I don't like it and I want Integer and or string value though that I used line 5 and 6 and because commented that in the code but not true.
second : It is very important result key array for me because that I understand Who has not received and who has received it and why ? thank you.

Comment: Possibly related to your first point about bigints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520487/json-bigint-as-string-removed-in-php-5-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a partial answer for your second point, to access the results in the json (tested in php 5.6):

```
foreach ($MyDecode->results as $result) {
    if (isset($result->error)) {
        echo 'Found error: ' . $result->error . PHP_EOL;
    } elseif (isset($result->message_id)) {
        echo 'Found message id: ' . $result->message_id . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found error: NotRegistered
Found error: NotRegistered
Found message id: 0:1513401047065944%93a06d80f9fd7ecd
Found message id: 0:1513401047066546%93a06d80f9fd7ecd
```

Comment: I test your code and it's worked like charm !!! just thing must I say you to I can't parse to string value from multicast_id key yet, even with your suggested solution...  !!! Thank you very much bra !!! @astrangeloop just

Comment: based on an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520487/json-bigint-as-string-removed-in-php-5-5, you can use preg_replace to convert the bigint to a string in the json before decoding:
`$MyString = sendFCMToMultiple($ids);`
`$MyString = preg_replace('/("multicast_id":\s*)(\d+)/', '\1"\2"', $MyString);`
`$MyDecode = json_decode($MyString);`
`var_dump($MyDecode->multicast_id);`
Gives:
`string(19) "7640049088650537742"`

Comment: really really thanks, I wish your best and I hope to every stage life always good luck bra!!! Thank you!!! 